# <p:columns> won't render when list-property of object is used

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to use `<p:columns>` but it **renders nothing** when I feed it with a `List` that is a property of the objects the enclosing `<p:dataTable>` is iterating over.

I **can use that list succesfully** in `<ui:repeat>` or access one of it's entries inside the `<p:dataTable>` using `<p:column>`. `<p:columns>` when a assign the list to a property of the backing bean.
**But when using the property of the `Car`-object** nothing is rendered at that place. There is no error message etc.

The part about `Dynamic Columns` in the [Primefaces 4.0 User Guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_4_0_edtn2.pdf) confuses me as in the code example `cars[colIndex]` is used but still the `<p:columns>` has a value other than `cars` - I don't how this is supposed to be used.

*Additional Info:

I need the list of columns for `<p:columns>` to be part of the class as I want to reuse the code for several classes with different properties and thus require different columns.*

the Facelets code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:messages />
<h:form>
    <!-- works -->
    <ui:repeat value="#{carBean.cars}" var="car">
        ui:repeat: #{car.features}
    </ui:repeat>

    <p:dataTable value="#{carBean.cars}" var="car">

       <!-- works too -->
       <p:column>
           p:column: #{car.features.get(0)}
       </p:column>

       <!-- works too -->
       <p:columns value="#{carBean.beanFeatures}" var="feature" columnIndexVar="colIndex">  
            carBean p:columns: #{feature}
       </p:columns>

       <!-- renders nothing -->
       <p:columns value="#{car.features}" var="feature" columnIndexVar="colIndex">  
            car p:columns: #{feature}
       </p:columns>

    </p:dataTable>

</h:form>
</html>
```

the backing bean:

```
package myPackage;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CarBean implements Serializable {

    List<Car> cars;
    List<String> beanFeatures;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        Car car1 = new Car();
        car1.features.add("windows");
        car1.features.add("fridge");
        Car car2 = new Car();
        car2.features.add("wheels");
        car2.features.add("nuclear engine");
        cars.add(car1);
        cars.add(car2);
        beanFeatures = car1.getFeatures();
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public List<String> getBeanFeatures() {
        return beanFeatures;
    }

    public void setBeanFeatures(List<String> beanFeatures) {
        this.beanFeatures = beanFeatures;
    }

}
```

the `Car` class

```
package myPackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Car {

    List<String> features = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getFeatures() {
        return features;
    }

    public void setFeatures(List<String> features) {
        this.features = features;
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for providing well-formed and testable code. Tip for next time: you can embed your `Car` class into the managed bean, having the whole java code in one class ;-)

Comment: Try give differents names for `var=""` and `columnIndexVar=""` attributes

Answer (score 1):

That's basically not the way Primefaces dynamic columns work. Your dynamic columns must be binded against a Managed Bean's property directly. There's no choice to dinamically stablish that value for each car iteration.

So, in short words, is not possible to have different columns for different table values. Table columns can be dinamically rendered, but this must be decided **before PrimeFaces starts looping over the values**.

If you have a look at [Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf), you'll find that.

However, it's possible to loop over car's features in the same columns using a `ui:repeat`, so you could have all its features in a single column:

```
<p:column>  
    <ui:repeat value="#{car.features}" var="feature">
        #{feature}
    </ui:repeat>
</p:column>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I need it the other way around: One column per `feature`.

Comment: Then you've to use an auxiliar class to bind to the table. Create an structure in order to keep all the possible features. Then, iterate over the cars and fill it with each car features. Resulting table will contain all the possible features, with the cell filled only if the car contains that info.

Comment: Sounds like a plan - that I don't grasp. Could you add a short example to your answer? Please :)

Comment: Are the possible features known at compile time?

Comment: Maybe you could try with a [subtable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSubTable.jsf)