# Primefaces - Combining two different list in a primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

Is it possible to create a datatable with 2 different lists?

`List<String>` -> I need this to label the rows
`List<List<Class>>` -> this one is for the table itself

it should look like this

```
 Date | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
1/1/1 | val  |      |      | val  |
1/2/1 |      |      |  val |      |
1/3/1 |      |  val |      |      |
```

the date columns is a list of strings
and the col1,col2,col3,col4 are the 2d list of the class.

I cannot do a 2d list of String where I can include the date column ,because the values on the datatable should be editable and should reflect to the backing bean.

Comment: Would u like to use dynamic column and rows?

Comment: You can use dynamic columns, but you have to know the column size before rendering the table. I mean, you can have col1, col2,..colx list, but you have to know x value before table gets rendered. You cannot have a list where x differs from a value to another. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563333/pcolumns-wont-render-when-list-property-of-object-is-used/19564259#comment29038465_19564259)

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. Actually I was able to create the table dynamically, but It was a 2d list of strings, where in the datecolumns is also included. But the problem is, how can I make it editable and reflect it to the database.